# open scala editor in cmd - Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: scala

How to open an editor (Notepad or Notepad++ or Atom or any Editor) from windows  command prompt from REPL

```
===============
scala >
===============
```

Adding one more question::
Is there any way to open an existing SCALA file from REPL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type this in REPL `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("notepad.exe")`

Comment: Hi Aamir, Thank you , that works actually ..one question how to open an existing scala file from REPL

Comment: @DbasePlsql Ususally, I would recommend that you ask another question for this. But in this case, you should really just look it up in the documentation first.

Comment: @DbasePlsql use Runtime.getRuntime.exec("notepad followed by filelocation") i.e if my Test.scala is located in D:/Scala/Test.scala then type this in REPL `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("notepad D://Scala/Test.scala")`

Comment: Hey.. Thank you Aamir .. Thats helpful :)

Comment: Hi Madoc, Thanks for your comment ..Your "Scala for Java programmers the Euler way" is nice - Subscribed :)